# How to see battery consumption per application (!!) over the past X hours on my MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, power

I asked this question a while back: [Stop MacBook from using up the battery while it is in sleep mode](https://superuser.com/questions/1686102/stop-macbook-from-using-up-the-battery-while-it-is-in-sleep-mode). And never got to the bottom of it.

I keeps happening, that I put my Mac in sleep (on a full battery), and bring it with me on a train or something - and on that day, the battery-Gods had thrown a curse on me: 10% battery left. **SIGH!!**

**Overarching question:** In order to debug this, I'm looking for a way I can figure out, which applications used (the most) energy for the past 12 hours (or so).

I know that it can be misleading, since maybe Chrome spend the most energy/battery, but it was my Docker-service that stopped my Mac from every sleeping (while barely consuming any energy/battery).

**Bonus points** if you can give me a terminal-command to run for: 'Kill everything that is stopping my Mac from going into proper sleep'.

---

### Solution attempt 1: Activity Monitor

I can see that there are some information in the Activity Monitor. Such as the column called: `12 hour Power`. I assume that is what I'm looking for.

It told me that 'Spotlight' consumed 73% (in the `12 hour Power`-column), the last time this happened. Hmm...

### Solution attempt 2: 3rd party application - or a command

I tried looking for a program or a terminal-command, that would get me some extra insight. But I couldn't find anything (that didn't look shady).

### Solution attempt 3: Lock screen vs sleep vs hibernate

I read this article here: [How to Choose a Sleep Mode for Your Mac](https://mackeeper.com/blog/mac-sleep-modes-explained/), which was good for my understanding, but not revolutionizing anything in my quest here.

The biggest difference after that article was, that I know more about when to use 'Screen lock':

[image: screen lock]

... and when to use 'Sleep':

[image: sleep]

For context, I'm mentioning that I'm using `hibernatemode 3`.

### Solution attempt 4: Look into `pmset`

By writing: `pmset -g` I got some extra info. But nothing that I could use for this particular case:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         15
 womp                 1
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by nfsd, sharingd, useractivityd)
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            0
```

As can be seen there, it says: `(sleep prevented by nfsd, sharingd, useractivityd)`.

**`sharingd`**

By Googling `sharingd` I can see that that is used by AirDrop. I read about [sharingd](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/sharingd/#:%7E:text=sharingd%20is%20used%20by%20the,in%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.9.) - and then disabled [AirDrop](http://www.rawinfopages.com/mac/content/disable-airdrop-mac-increased-security-public).

**`useractivityd`**

I don't know what this is. But it disappears by itself, if I simply run `pmset -g` again and again.

**`nfsd`**

This I know quite a bit about, since when I played with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). It's the Network File System Daemon. One can read more about it with the command: `man nfsd`.

I stopped that with: `sudo nfsd stop` (it can be started simply with a reboot or with: `sudo nfsd start`). It's what handles sync'ing of files to a Vagrant Virtual machine - and maybe also to a Docker container (I'm assuming the last bit here).

---

After having gone through this, then `pmset -g` doesn't display any programs nor daemons 'preventing sleep'.

So now I'll try, if I know that battery will be important, to run `pmset -g` and see if any service is preventing sleep (and also checking that column in the Activity Monitor). And trying to kill those applications first.

But I would still love to get some graphs over which applications used how much energy/battery, of the past X hours.

Comment: Intel or Arm? M1? M2?

Comment: I'm on a MacBook Pro from 2019, Intel processor.

Comment: I also wish there was a way to know which apps used how much power over the last X hours. Just upgraded to Sonoma and my battery drains completely overnight with the lid closed. Others are also having this issue. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255160610